# How can I call my music class and play music within a while loop which executes my lines under the line which calls the music class?

Tags: java

I have two classes and I wanted to know how I can call my music class (MP3 class2) to make the song play throughout my while loop in class one. My issue is when I use `MP3.main(args);` in class one the while loop in class one is not executing what's below the line of `MP3.main(args);`. Therefore, the text "Enter a command" isn't being display. I think I need to recreate my MP3 class and pass through the parameter if that's the correct use of terminology. Sorry I'm still new to java.

Please note I have removed lots of code from class one as it's for a project.

Incase anyone asks me why don't you just delete class one and move the text over to class two this is not an option long story short.

**CLASS 1 ** Trying to play music that's in class two but the program isn't executing what's below the line of `MP3.main(args);` in my while loop.

```
public class ClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create the loop
        while (true) {
            MP3.main(args);
            System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
        }
    }
}
```

**CLASS 2 MP3 CLASS**

```
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


class MP3 {
    private static String filename = null;

    // constructor that takes the name of an MP3 file
    public MP3(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    // play the MP3 file to the sound card
    public static void play() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            Player player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    // test client
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = ("Growth.mp3");
        MP3 mp3 = new MP3(filename);
        mp3.play();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis     = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            Player player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Static is a memory tool, not an access tool. You shouldn't use it in this way

Comment: Are you sure the `player.play()` isn't hanging?

Comment: possible duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104942/jlayer-javazoom-player-can-not-stop-mp3

Comment: you may need to call `player.stop() ` to stop the player. `.play()` is blocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look in the `play()` method reveals that this is a blocking operation. You could invoke the method within a separate thread, so you can test, when the player has finished and reinvoke the play method, like so:

**MP3.java**

```java
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MP3 {

    private final String filename;

    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private Player player;

    public MP3(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void playAsync() {
        if (executorService == null) {
            executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            executorService.submit(this::play);
        }
    }

    public void playForever() {
        while (true) {
            sleep();
            if (player == null || player.isComplete()) {
                System.out.println("Still playing: " + filename);
                stopAsync();
                playAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopAsync() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.close();
            player = null;
        }
        if (executorService != null) {
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService = null;
        }
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```java
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = ("Growth.mp3");
        MP3 mp3 = new MP3(filename);
        mp3.playForever();
    }
}
```